# Create Azure VM from Snapshot if Disk Deleted Possible?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, hard-drive, snapshot

We **deleted a VM** as it was no longer needed. Prior to deleting we took a **snapshot**. The VM **hard drive (OS) disk** still exists but we're looking to clean up unused resources. If I **delete this disk**, can I **create a new VM** using the **snapshot** or does the snapshot require the disk in order to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are using managed disk, you shouldn't have any issues.

- The snapshot does not require disk.
- You cannot create VM from snapshot but you can create a disk from snapshot and then create a VM from that disk.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, using managed disks and I meant create a disk from the snapshot, then create a VM from the disk. Thank you for the information, this is exactly what I was looking for.